# Webpack bundle number of times to build

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Is it necessary to create a bundle.min.js with webpack everytime you do an npm run start? doesn't it automatically update behind the scenes as you save while the server is running?

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming your `npm run start` executes `webpack-dev-server`)

Nope, `webpack-dev-server` serves content from memory.

This means that when you run `webpack-dev-server`, it doesn't create any build files. In other words, you don't need to explicitly see a bundle.min.js on your build directory unless you're building for production, in which case you'd be using `webpack` instead of `webpack-dev-server`.